# unable to send email using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, smtp

What am I doing wrong? Should be so simple.After I execute - nothing happens, no errors, no email. Nothing. 
I am using Jupyter.

```
def send_email(user, pwd, recipient, subject, body):
    import smtplib

    gmail_user = 'email@email.com'
    gmail_pwd = 'pass'
    FROM = 'email@email.com'
    TO = 'email@email.com'
    SUBJECT = 'Test'
    TEXT = 'Hello, this is test email'

    # Prepare actual message
    message = """From: %s\nTo: %s\nSubject: %s\n\n%s
    """ % (FROM, ", ".join(TO), SUBJECT, TEXT)
    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.login(gmail_user, gmail_pwd)
        server.sendmail(FROM, TO, message)
        server.close()
        print ('successfully sent the mail')
    except:
        print ("failed to send mail")
```

Comment: get rid of the `try/except` and look at the exception message

Comment: it is only function definiton. Did you execute this function ? ie. `send_email("me@gmai.com", "MyPaSwOrD", "you@gmail.com", "Money for you", "Hi, I have money for you.")`

Comment: @furas thanks. I'm new to python. I did what you said. But now I got another error: `SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials e26sm1483410pfi.10 - gsmtp')`. But thats another question. Thanks for your help. Post your answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: code uses hardcoded values to login and send mail - and error shows that it used incorrect login and/or password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is only function definiton. You have to execut it like

```
send_email("me@gmai.com", "MyPaSwOrD", "you@gmail.com", "Money for you", "Hi")
```

But your code will not use this data because it has hardcoded values inside.